# I want to hide the navigation bar and display only the back button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationitem

navigationBarTitle is hidden.
How can I display the back button in this state?

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            Text("text")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

When you do the following, a blank will appear at the top.
Also, if you scroll, a bar will be displayed.

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            Text("text")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Back button is a navigation item of navigation bar, so how do you imaging to see part of navigation bar having hidden bar itself? Answer - you can't. If you don't want to use navigation bar, create custom button with chevron image - the look & feel would be the same.

Comment: yes .. if you just need back button ... create custom button instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to add custom button instead of navigationBar

```
struct DestinationView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
        Button(action: {
           self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "backward.fill").padding()
            Spacer()
        }
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)

    }
}
```

[image]